# Using AngularJS to create an instant search by querying an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, search, filtering

This is going to be a rather longwinded question, so please bear with me...

I have an array of about 25-30 items. They are sorted through various filters such as brand, type, material, size, etc.. How can I go about building a searchable filter. All of the ones I've seen just include a `filter:query |` in their filters. However I can't get mine to query my existing array.

Here is what my array looks like, only going to show 1 item to keep size down..

```
$scope.products = [
{
src: 'images/img/image1.jpg',
name:  'XXX-1A',
brand: 'Brand A',
material: 'dry',
size: '00',
type: 'dry pipe',
color:'red'
}];
```

Function for filtering (only included 1 to save space):

```
$scope.brandIncludes = [];

    $scope.includeBrand = function(brand) {
        var i = $.inArray(brand, $scope.brandIncludes);
        if (i > -1) {
            $scope.brandIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.brandIncludes.push(brand);
        }
    }

    $scope.brandFilter = function(products) {
        if ($scope.brandIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(products.brand, $scope.brandIncludes) < 0)
                return;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is what I am using to filter from the HTML, I am using checkboxes to select each filter:

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="p in products |  
filter:brandFilter | 
filter:materialFilter | 
filter:typeFilter | 
filter:styleFilter">
</div>
```

My search bar mark up:

```
  <div class="filtering">
    <div class="search-sect">
     <input name="dbQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search pieces" class="search-input" ng-model="query"/>
  </div>
```

One of the filter's mark up:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeStyle('adaptor')"/>Adaptor<br>
```

Now that you have all the code, here are some of the things I've tried that don't seem to be running right:

**My Attempt:**

Search bar:

```
  <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query"/>
```

Filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in products | filter:query | orderBy: orderList">
```

I understand that to some experienced with angular, this is a relatively easy task, but I am just learning and can't seem to wrap my head around searching a query. It's probably a simple solution that I am overlooking. This is my first Angular app and I am trying to bite off more than I can chew in order to learn more.

I appreciate all responses, thanks in advance!

*As per request: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/RNyYmz?editors=101)*

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Certainly, I have the whole thing in a code pen currently, updated it onto my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple built-in angular filter is not smart enough to to work with your checkbox design, so try writing a custom filter. You will need to bind the checkboxes you mentioned to variables in your scope, e.g. `brandFilterIsEnabled`. See the tutorial for [writing custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). Here is a working example.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name:'foo',
    color:'red'
  },{
    name:'bar',
    color:'blue'
  },{
    name:'baz',
    color:'green'
  }];

  $scope.searchNames = true;
  $scope.searchColors = true;

  $scope.$watch('searchColors', function(){
    $scope.searchKeys = [ $scope.searchNames ? 'name' : null, $scope.searchColors ? 'color' : null ];
  });
  $scope.$watch('searchNames', function(){
    $scope.searchKeys = [ $scope.searchNames ? 'name' : null, $scope.searchColors ? 'color' : null ];
  });
});

myApp.filter('advancedSearch', function($filter) {
  return function(data, keys, query) {
    results = [];
    if( !query ){
      return data;
    } else {
      
       angular.forEach( data, function( obj ){
          var matched = false;
          angular.forEach( keys, function( key ){
             if( obj[key] ){  
                // match values using angular's built-in filter
                if ($filter('filter')([obj[key]], query).length > 0){
                   // don't add objects to results twice if multiple
                   // keys have values that match query
                   if( !matched ) {
                      results.push(obj);
                   }
                   matched = true;
                }
             }
          });
       });
    }
    return results;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <input type='checkbox' ng-model='searchNames'>search names</input>
     <input type='checkbox' ng-model='searchColors'>search colors</input>
     <input type='text' ng-model='query'>search objects</input>
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | advancedSearch : searchKeys : query">
         <span style="color:{{item.color}}">{{item.name}}</span>
        </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: .... *you don't need custom filters* ..... *write some simple custom filters for this* ....huh? One of those is not relevant, surely?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you, the `:query` in your example is the search option? Followed by checking if previous filters are enabled?

Comment: Sorry, rewrote answer quickly.  What I meant was, with the addition of the checkboxes enabling and disabling parts of search scope, custom filters will be necessary.

Comment: Just realized that I forgot to include the filtering method I was using in JS, edited my question to include this

Comment: @user4470749 Correct, query is the value bound to the text field search box. The second input to the filter is the boolean flag telling the filter whether it is enabled or not.

Comment: @user4470749 Looks like you're on the right track; you just need to register that function as a filter and give it a name.  See the tutorial I linked to (tldr: `angular.module('myModule', []).filter('filterName', function() {....});`)

Comment: I believe I already had to make the custom filters, but query still doesn't want to search the array? I've seen an option where you build an array of strings of keywords, but this project will potentially have more than 500+ items in end result and at 7 keywords/item, that would be a lengthy array that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Oh so I need another function like the one previous, but to target my search input? EDIT: I'm sorry, I'm still not following, I just can't seem to wrap my head around the logic..

Comment: @user4470749 Yes.  Like I said though, once you get this working you can refactor to just use one custom filter that you pass a list of enabled keys and the search value.

Comment: I've been trying for the past half hour, and like I said, I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.. :/

Comment: @user4470749 No problem, give me a little time to put a working demo together.

Comment: That would be extremely helpful, I was following you for a bit, but then I was just lost. lol I've been building this model I have for the past few weeks by piecing demos together. So I know the syntax, it's just translating it into original functions is hard for me.

Comment: @user4470749 Ok, added a runnable code snippet.  Hope you find it helpful!  The filter itself is actually fairly general and reusable - I may use it in my own projects.  The controller's watch statements are a little clunky and could be refactored.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72431/discussion-between-user4470749-and-alexma).

Comment: Already mentioned it, but I just had to sit down and drill into this example a little bit more. Great answer, thanks for the help Alex!